# how can i return a char value from function? in c unix

Tags: c, unix

To write programs in C which reads lines from a file
text, whose name will give the user at runtime.
The program should select a random line of the file and to print the screen, giving the user a time X to type the words seen on the screen.
The time of X depends on the length of each phrase and you can consider that each character will give the user 1 second.
If the message is printed correctly and on time, the user receives congratulations. If the error message printed (and on time), then the user is informed precisely about the mistakes he has done.

Finally, if time runs out before printing the message, then asks the user if he wants to continue and provided the user answers yes to the above sequence is repeated for a new random line of the file, otherwise the program terminates.

Can someone tell me what I have done wrong; I would have been easier if you write the code you need ...

thanks nik

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void catch_alarm (int sig)
{
    char ans[2];

    printf ("Operation timed out. Exiting...\n");
    printf ("thes mia akoma eukairia?[y/n]\n");
    scanf ("%s", ans);

    exit (0);
}
void exodos (int sig)
{
    printf ("termatismos ergasias... \n");
    signal (SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);

    exit (0);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, j, x, count, gram[80];
    i = j = count = 0;

    char arxeio[25], grammi[80], buf[80][80], protash[80],  ch, ans[2];
    FILE *fp;

    printf("dwse to onoma tou arxeiou pou thes na anoixeis: \n");
    scanf("%s", arxeio);

    do
    { 
        fp = fopen( arxeio, "r");
        while ( (ch = getc(fp)) != EOF )
        { 
            buf[i][j] = ch;
            if ( buf[i][j] == '\n' )
            {
                ++i;
                gram[i] = j;
                j = 0;
            }
                ++j;
        }

        fclose(fp);

        // edw vazoume tin rand kai to apotelesma tis sto 4 parakatw
        x = rand() % i;   
        j = 0;

        while (j<=gram[x+1])
        { 
            printf("%c", buf[x][j]);
            j++;
        }


        /* elenxos entos xronou an oxi TIME OUT... */
        signal(SIGALRM, catch_alarm);
        fflush(stdout);
        alarm(gram[x+1]);
        scanf("%s",protash);

        if (ans[0] == 'n')  
            signal(SIGQUIT, exodos);

        /* elenxos or8hs eisagwghs dedomenwn*/
        j = 0;
        while ( j<=(gram[x+1]-2) )
        {  
            if ( buf[x][j+1] != protash[j] )
                printf("anti gia %c egrapses %c\n", buf[x][j+1], protash[j]);
            else    
                printf("swsto\n");

            ++j;
        }

        /* deuterh eukairia... */


    }
    while ( ans[0] == 'y' ); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: two things.  1) Proper formatting (and English comments) would help us a lot.  2) What is the program failing to do?  Are you getting a compile error or unexpected run-time behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The example you pasted here is slightly hard to follow, but it looks like you're trying to make a signal handler return a char. This isn't possible because the signal handler is required to be void  (although it is in general possible for a function to return a char).

The simplest work around for this would be a global (static?) variable instead.

Also note that printf and scanf are not [async-safe](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers). The work around for that would be to set a "flag" somewhere and then notice that this has been set later on.

**Edit** I think this is a simplified example of what you're trying to achieve here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int timeout = 0;

static void catch_alarm(int sig) {
   if (SIGALRM != sig || 0 != timeout)
      abort();

   timeout = 1;
}

int main() {
   char buf[80];

   signal(SIGALRM, catch_alarm); //TODO: check return!

   printf("Type some stuf:\n");
   fflush(NULL);
   alarm(5);
   int read = -1;
   while (read  < 0 && !timeout) {
      read = scanf("%80s", buf);
   }

   if (timeout) {
     printf("Time out, do something else\n");
   }

   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Certainly simplest, but probably not best.

Comment: agreed and I just noticed the non async-safe calls in the signal handler anyway, which exacerbate the problem too.

Comment: I think that scanf will return with an error and set errno to EINTR in the event that the SIGALRM was received.  It might be better just to set a flag (to distinguish SIGALRM from other signals) in the handler and deal with it on detected EINTR for a library call.  I don't think there's any way to avoid a global flag variable here.

Comment: @JeremyP: I think it's true that EINTR will be returned when using signal() like this, but I think sigaction() + SA_RESTART would break that behaviour for example.